# sort an unmodifiable collection, remove duplicated according to element of collection

Tags: java, string, sorting

So I have this code of fetching some product instances, which would give a product id and some other things. Now that for some reasons, the database returns some duplicated information and I need to remove the duplicated ones and sort the collection into alphabetical order according to the product id. Product id value are names like alex, robert, stephanie, etc. I did a search around but still dont know how to solve, probably because I am new to Java so I would like to ask if you could help me to get a direct answer to the problem.

```
public static Collection<Product> getProductInstances() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(INSTANCES.values());
}

public interface Product {    
    public String getProductId();
}
```

Comment: It would be easiest to copy the collection into a SortedSet, e.g. TreeSet. This would automatically handle the reduplication for you.

Comment: @AndyTurner Comments are not intended to provide solutions. Write a proper answer _please_.

Comment: You should fix the database query before trying to fix that in code...

Comment: the database has duplicated information i think. and that means to fix the inputting source or how the input is handled. but it is a bit complicated in my case. is it possible just to fix it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can't sort (which modifies) an unmodifiable collection.

However, given a collection, you can get a sorted and deduped Set as follows:

```
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Product::getId));
set.addAll(getProductInstances());
```

Iteration over the set will be in id order, and being a Set will have no duplicates - a TreeSet defines "equal" as the elements comparing as equal.